# What is the difference between workerNum and localExcutors in the dolphindb configuration file?

Tags: dolphindb

What is the difference between workerNum and localExcutors in the dolphindb configuration file? In tutorial, we often see that workerNum is 1 larger than localExcutors,that is why?

Answer (score 0):

A worker is designed to receive and coordinate users' request. The workerNum limits the number of jobs a DolphinDB instance can process simultaneously. If the requested job is simple, the worker just does it by itself. Otherwise, the coordinating worker breaks the job down into sub tasks, and then assigns those sub-tasks to itself and the local executors in a pool. Upon completion of all sub-tasks, the coordinating worker merges the individual results from sub-tasks and then returns it to the client.

In summary, a worker can serve as both coordinator and executor while a local executor can only be used as a job executor.